# How to post with PHP to a facebook group?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using a page access token and posting on the page wall fine.

Now I want to post from my page to a facebook group that this page belongs.

I am using simple code like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Facebook\Facebook;

class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fb = new Facebook([
            'app_id' => env('app_id'),
            'app_secret' => env('app_secret'),
        ]);
    }

    public function post(): void
    {
        $response = $this->fb->post(
            sprintf('/%s/feed', 'theFacebookGroupIdHere'),
            ['message' => 'a test message'],
            $this->config['fb']['pageAccessToken']
        );
    }
}
```

And I get always error:

```
Unsupported request - method type: post
message = "Unsupported request - method type: post"
type = "GraphMethodException"
code = {int} 100
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong ? I saw a lot of posts online using this approach (in python and other languages)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- download facebook sdk

Step 2- create an config src file

Comment: I have downloaded the facebook sdk already (included via composer as shown in the code above). I can post fine to the page feed, I get the error when trying to post to a group..